# Limits, Tilting and Derived Categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\{A_n\}_{n>0}$ be a family of algebras such that for every $n>0$ there exist a triangulated equivalence $D(A_n) \cong D(A_{n+1})$. So all these algebras are derived equivalent.

Take $A=colim_{n>0}(A_n)$.

1. Does $D(A) \cong D(A_{1}) $?
2. If not, what is the relation between $D(A)$ and the categories $D(A_{n})$?
3. If we assume that for each $n>0$, there exist a tilting complex $T_n$ that gives the desired equivalence of derived categories, can all these complexes be taken in a common category where $T=colim_{n>0} T_n$ exists? Is $T$ tilting? What would be the resulting derived category of the endomorphism algebra of $T$?

Comment: There's no reason to expect colimits to play nicely with derived equivalences. At the very least you want homotopy colimits. But I also don't understand what shape of diagram you're looking at, or what the diagram has to do with the derived equivalences.

Comment: If the equivalence $D(A_n)\cong D(A_{n+1})$ has nothing to do with the map $A_n\to A_{n+1}$ used to form the colimit, there is no reason at all to expect this to be true.  For instance, if $A_n=k[x]$ for all $n$ but the map $A_n\to A_{n+1}$ sends $x$ to $0$, the colimit will just be $k$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: What do you mean that at the very least one wants homotopy limits?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Can one do something to make the equivalence of derived categories has something to do with the maps to form the colimit?

Comment: So your question is something like: given only a sequence of algebras and equivalences $D(A_n)\cong D(A_{n+1})$, can one canonically construct a sequence of homomorphisms $A_n\to A_{n+1}$ somehow related such that the colimit is nicely behaved?  I don't see any reason to expect anything like this to be true.  For instance, if $A_n=M_2(k)$ for $n$ even and $A_n=M_3(k)$ for $n$ odd, there are no homomorphisms from $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ at all!